# Is LINQ slower than calling stored procedures?

Tags: linq, stored-procedures

I'm hoping that we will be overhauling our system to use ASP.NET MVC, however all of the examples provided tend to use LINQ to SQL.  We were told by a LINQ developer than it is actually slower than calling a store procedure.

Furthermore, how would you call a stored procedure for output using MVC?  I'm not entirely sure LINQ would meet our needs as our stored procedures are extremely large, and complex.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can in fact call stored procedures from Linq to SQL.
Take a look at this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx
I'd argue there is no performance drop in using Linq as it is simply a way to express your sql code in C#/VB.NET. It will get translated into plain sql.
This is the old fight of Stored Procedures VS normal queries, Linq is not really a part of the question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking.  LINQ is literally that a "link" as such from .NET code to SQL.  How are the sprocs parameters exposed though?

Comment: If you creat a stored proc that receives parameters it will be exposed in .NET as a method with those same parameters, but with the .NET types.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is slower in certain edge cases, in those cases you can call the sprocs from L2S.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that LINQ to SQL has been deprecated and LINQ to Entities is the tech to use.

Comment: Actually, for those of you who've downvoted, he's half right. The ADO.NET team has discontinued the Linq to SQL project. That doesn't justify using Linq to Entities instead, but... ;)

Comment: Nope, not discontinued, just not in active development.  They have said that there is potential for new work but it is hardly deprecated.